# forceExpand: error parsing jsonObject in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working on an soap proxy in WSO2 EI. when I invoke a rest service this is the output :

```
Payload: "{\"HasError\":false,\"Mensaje\":\"OK\"}"
```

The client can not change this return. The exception I'm getting is:

```
ERROR {org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl} -  forceExpand:    error parsing data soruce document for element jsonObject {org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl}
```

Some idea to correct this behavior in WSO2 EI?, knowing that it is not a formal json.

thanking you for your support.

Comment: How do you invoke rest service? (I hope you don't use browser to do it)

Comment: Hi, I use  <call><endpoint key="RestPostEndpoint"/></call>, the service return a string.

Comment: in some cases the REST services return for example a string like "OK" or another that does not have a formal json format, but the client can not adjust it.

Comment: in essence wso2 ei can not parse well because it expects a json document. What could be done in those cases?

Comment: Documentation states that WSOEI will make decision base on content type (details in here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters)
Always set a proper messageType of message and Content-Type of request.

Comment: It looks like you send xml content with content type application/json or conversely

Comment: do you want to perform any mediation on this payload or just want to pass it to the client

Comment: Hi @JulioCejas
Did u get any solutions for this? i am also facing same issue in WSO2 EI 6.1.1.